# Using Math_BigInteger Library with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway

a payment gateway I'm using requires me to use a PHP library called 
http://pear.php.net/package/Math_BigInteger

which uses

http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_RSA

I have successfully namespace both libraries but when I try to use it I get the following error

```
ErrorException in BigInteger.php line 548:
Use of undefined constant MATH_BIGINTEGER_MODE - assumed 'MATH_BIGINTEGER_MODE'
```

Comment: How are you using it?

Comment: the Crypt_RSA library is in App\PaymentGateway\Crypt folder and Math_BigInteger library is in \App\PaymentGateway\Math\  folder

Comment: `MATH_BIGINTEGER_MODE` is a constant that would be defined by constructing a BigInteger object, e.g. `$x = new BigInteger("99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999");` is this what you are doing?

Comment: are you saying that the object is not initiating?

Comment: I'm asking how you're using the class. Can you share a bit of code of how you're trying to use it?